# web2py / websockets - the example in websocket_messaging.py doesn't work?

Tags: websocket, tornado, web2py

I copied exactly as is, the two actions in the `gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py` file.

controllers/debug.py:

```
def index():
    form=LOAD('debug','ajax_form',ajax=True)
    script=SCRIPT('''
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          var callback=function(e){alert(e.data)};
          if(!web2py_websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888/realtime/mygroup',callback))
            alert("html5 websocket not supported by your browser, try Google Chrome");
        });
    ''')
    return dict(form=form, script=script)

def ajax_form():
    form=SQLFORM.factory(Field('message'))
    if form.accepts(request,session):
        from gluon.contrib.websocket_messaging import websocket_send
        websocket_send(
            'http://127.0.0.1:8888',form.vars.message,'mykey','mygroup')
    return form
```

views/debug/index.html:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form}}
{{=script}}
```

But when I connect to the website I see the following error message:

`Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:8888/realtime/mygroup`

I start the server like this:

```
python gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py -k mykey -p 8888
```

and the message there is:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:403 GET /realtime/mygroup (127.0.0.1) 0.55ms
```

but I can see any message I send, it just doesn't pop up through the `alert` function.

As a disclaimer I'm complete new to java and websockets so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this locally (i.e., is your browser on the same machine that is running web2py and Tornado)?

Comment: yes, does that make a difference? I did it with a "private browsing" session and a normal session, hoping the two don't collide in some way

Comment: by private I mean that I had two firefox instances open try to send eachother a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the problem was that my `websocket_messaging.py` was missing the following:

```
def check_origin( self , origin ):
    return True
```

in the `class DistributeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler)`

even though the https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py had this correctly implemented. (look at line 149)

I am running web2py 2.11.2 so no idea if this is expected or not and I also updated through the web2py admin interface not by downloading a new web2py instance. Not sure if that could've caused the problem.

Either way solved!